# Error opening ODBC database connection in Visual Studios

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, odbc, intersystems-cache

I hope to make this short and clear enough. I connect to the ODBC without any issues when using Crystal Reports and have previously used the below setup in VS to create apps and it had worked fine. However, now I am receiving the exception below when I call con.Open();
I was wondering how I am able to resolve this issue. Thanks!

> {"ERROR [S1000] [Cache ODBC][State : S1000][Native Code
>   417]\r\n[C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS
>   Express\iisexpress.exe]\r\nAccess Denied\r\nERROR [01000]
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The driver doesn't support the
>   version of ODBC behavior that the application requested (see
>   SQLSetEnvAttr)."}

My connection string and methods looks like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
<remove name="AvatarDBPM"/>
<remove name="AvatarDBCWS"/>
<add name="AvatarDBPM" connectionString="DRIVER={InterSystems ODBC};SERVER=0.0.0.0;PORT=4972;DATABASE=AVPM4972127001;UID=SYSTEMCODE:UN;PWD=MyPsswd;"/>
```

```
public DataAccess(string from_date, string to_date)
        {
            this.from_date = from_date;
            this.to_date = to_date;
            LOSList = new List<LOS_View_Definition>();
            this.PMConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AvatarDBPM"].ConnectionString;
        }

        public List<LOS_View_Definition> GetLOSList()
        {
            #region Command
            var command = "my query here";
            #endregion

            #region get value from DB
            try
            {
                using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(PMConnectionString))
                {
                    con.Open();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try another driver. There are 4 ODBC drivers installed with Cache:

ODBC Version: 2.5, 3.5

Bitness:      32, 64

Also, are you sure, that PORT is not 1972? 
Additionally you may supply `AUTHENTICATION METHOD=0` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a version of the ODBC driver which is compliant to the requested ODBC specification.If you are using a 64 bit system you should also be using a 64 bit ODBC driver. This error occurs when there is a mismatch between the version of driver installed and the system you are using to compile.